# find strong and weak links given customer history

Tags: java

Two items are strongly linked if the same customer has purchased both of them. Two items are weakly linked if they are strongly or weakly linked to a third item.

Input:

`{"first:abc","first:hij", "second:hij", "second:klm", "third:nop","fourth:qrs", "fourth:abc", "first:def", "fifth:klm", "fifth:tuv"}`

"First/Second/Third/Forth/Fifth" are cutomerID while the "ABC, HIJ" ect are item ids. They are seperated by a ":".

Goal: Find the number of Strong and Weak links for a given item.

Example: For "ABC" and the above input array of strings the output should be

`[3,2]`

The Strong links are **QRS , HIJ, DEF** and the weak links are **KLM,TUV**

**Method:**

```
public int[] getLinkCount(String itemId, String[] orderHist) {

}
```

What I have been able to figure out is:

1. Walk though the array and for each customer create a item list.
   So basically its a HashMap of Customers. The Key would be the
   customerID and the value would be a ArrayList of itemID
2. For each
   item in HapMap check if the arraylist has the itemId. If yes then return the arrayList and store these itemId in a strongLinks array.
3. Remove duplicates from the strongList array. Now you have the strong
   links for a given itemId. You can return the count.

No idea if this is the most efficient or not. Also stuck on now how to find the **WEAK Links**.

Answer (score 1):

I currently do not have an IDE, so I can't provide a full program by now, but I try to outline the idea. Finding strong links seems to be generally OK the way you did, but you perhaps better merge it with also finding weak links at the same time by traversing on your hashmap in a recursive way, starting from those customers whose item list contains the particular element

In this case customer "first" and "fourth" have item "ABC" in their item list

- Customer "first" also has items "HIJ" and "DEF" in his list, these are strong links to "ABC". So search should continue with those customers whose item list contain these elements. In this case customer "second" also has item "HIJ" and besides that he also has "KLM", so "KLM" is a weak link to "ABC". There aren't any other customers who have "DEF" in their item list so we stop here. You should continue to search for those customers whose item list contains "KLM", and you will find customer "fifth" whose item list also contains "TUV" besides, so that is also a weak link to "ABC". There aren't any other customers who have "TUV" in their item list so we stop here.
- Customer "fourth" has item "QRS" which is a strong link to "ABC". There aren't any other customers who have "QRS" in their item list so we stop here.

Comment: i knew this smelled like a recursive solution.... If you get access to an IDE i would appreciate a few code hints... Anyways let me also work on this.

Answer (score 1):

Here a working version. See comments in the code:

```
package strong;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


public class Strong {

    /**
     * Are item1 and item2 strongly linked ?
     * @param item1 the first item for example "abc"
     * @param item2 the second item for example "hij"
     * @param groups example: [[nop], [tuv, klm], [qrs, abc], [abc, def, hij], 
     * [hij, klm]]
     * @return true if item1 and item2 are strongly linked 
     */
    public static boolean stronglyLinked(String item1, String item2, 
            Collection<Set<String>> groups) {

        // true if groups contains a set with item1 and item2
        return groups.stream().
                anyMatch(g-> g.contains(item1) && g.contains(item2));
    }

    /**
     * Are item1 and item2 weakly linked ?
     * @param item1 the first item for example "abc"
     * @param item2 the second item for example "hij"
     * @param groups example: [[nop], [tuv, klm], [qrs, abc], [abc, def, hij], 
     * [hij, klm]]
     * @return true if item1 and item2 are weakly linked 
     */
    public static boolean weaklyLinked(String item1, String item2, 
            Collection<Set<String>> groups) {

        // call private implementation with bag parameter (to avoid infinite
        // recursion).
        return weaklyLinked(item1, item2, groups, new HashSet());
    }


    /**
     * Get strongly and weakly link count for the given item
     * @param itemId the item
     * @param orderHist for example: {"first:abc","first:hij", "second:hij", 
     * "second:klm", "third:nop","fourth:qrs", "fourth:abc", "first:def", 
     * "fifth:klm", "fifth:tuv"}
     * @return an array with [0] => strongly linked count, [1] => weakly linked
     * count.
     */
    public static int[] getLinkCount(String itemId, String[] orderHist) {

        // get groups of items bought together for example:
        // [[nop], [tuv, klm], [qrs, abc], [abc, def, hij], [hij, klm]]
        final Collection<Set<String>> groups = Arrays.stream(orderHist).
                map(o-> o.split(":")).
                // for example map "first:abs" to ["first", "abc"] 

                collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o-> o[0], 
                        Collectors.mapping(o-> o[1], Collectors.toSet()))).
                values();
                // group by customerId but keep only values (groups are 
                // important but customer are not). 

        // get the set of strongly linked items
        final Set<String> stronglyLinkedItems = groups.stream().
                flatMap(g-> g.stream()).
                // we get someting like: [nop, tuv, klm, qrs, abc, abc, def, 
                // hij]

                filter(item-> !item.equals(itemId)).
                // select only item != itemId

                distinct().
                // optimization. but stronglyLinked is not so costly (so may be 
                // removed)

                filter(item-> stronglyLinked(item, itemId, groups)).
                // select only item strongly linked with item

                collect(Collectors.toSet());
                // make a set from that stream

        // weeklyLinked items
        final Set<String> weaklyLinkedItems = groups.stream().
                flatMap(g-> g.stream()).
                // we get someting like: [nop, tuv, klm, qrs, abc, abc, def, 
                // hij]

                filter(item-> !item.equals(itemId)).
                // select only item != itemId

                filter(item-> !stronglyLinkedItems.contains(item)).
                // remove strongly linked items (alreay in stronglyLinkedItems
                // set).

                distinct().
                // remove duplicate. it's only an optimization we don't want 
                // to compute costly weaklyLinked() on duplicate (not needed).

                filter(item-> weaklyLinked(item, itemId, groups)).
                // select only item weakly linked with itemId

                collect(Collectors.toSet());
                // make a set 

        // return the result array
        return IntStream.of(
                stronglyLinkedItems.size(), 
                weaklyLinkedItems.size()).
                toArray();
    }

    /**
     * main
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String orderHist[] = {
            "first:abc","first:hij", "second:hij", "second:klm", "third:nop",
            "fourth:qrs", "fourth:abc", "first:def", "fifth:klm", "fifth:tuv"};
        int[] result = getLinkCount("abc", orderHist); 
        System.out.println(result[0]);
        System.out.println(result[1]);   
    }

    private static boolean weaklyLinked(String item1, String item2, 
            Collection<Set<String>> groups, Set<Set<String>> bag) {

        // if (item1, item2) has already been explored then return false
        // this is needed to avoid infinite recursion
        if (bag.stream().anyMatch(s-> s.contains(item1) && s.contains(item2))) {
            return false;
        }   

        // add (item1, item2) to the bag
        bag.add(Stream.of(item1, item2).collect(Collectors.toSet()));

        return groups.stream().
                flatMap(g-> g.stream()).
                // we get someting like:
                // [nop, tuv, klm, qrs, abc, abc, def, hij]

                filter(item-> !item.equals(item1) && !item.equals(item2)).
                // filter for removing item1 and item2 from the stream

                anyMatch(item-> (stronglyLinked(item1, item, groups) ||
                        weaklyLinked(item1, item, groups, new HashSet(bag))) &&
                                (stronglyLinked(item2, item, groups) ||
                        weaklyLinked(item2, item, groups, new HashSet(bag))));
                // any item strongly or weakly linked with item1 and item2 =>
                // if yes return true
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good. Is there a way to do this with core objects like arrays/linked lists? I think using Collections and all its fancy methods goes against the essence of the HW problem. They really want you to think and solve.

Comment: Yes i have used java 8 lambda expression. It's not fancy but different (functional programming). If you write and post your code for strongly linked (very easy to do). I will do the weakly linked for you and i will use your data structure in pure imperative form.